# Passing model data to asp.net mvc EditorTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, editortemplates

ScottGu in this post [link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx) shows how one can utilize EditorTemplates for things such as a Country DropDownList. My question is how can one pass a dynamic list of Countries to the EditorTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass it in [ViewData](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx) and feed ViewData from and ActionFilter if the data is required very often (although arguable it is an [anti-pattern](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/18/the-filter-viewdata-anti-pattern.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most elegant solution is using a Custom Attribute, you can later access Model metadata using: ViewData.ModelMetadata.

e.g:

```
 [Foreign(Type="DropDown", TableName="Countries")]
   public int IdCountry { get; set; }
```

where ForeignAttribute is a class you must declare, and later use it to build your editor template.

Answer (score 1):

Even better you make the partial view strongly typed and pass the model to the EditorFor helper

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SelectedCountry, Model.AvailableCountries)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get EditorForModel() to figure this out for the sub elements?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Benja's answer

You can also use the [AdditionaMetaData(key,value)] attribute in a similar fashion without having to define your own attribute. Key and value have to be strings.

The extra data can be retrieved in the view with: @ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["DropDownData"]